# Update value column if other column value is met

Tags: mysql, sql

There is probably an easy solution, but I'm just a rookie when it comes to databases and couldn't find a solution.

I've got two columns. Something like:

```
Meta_value | Meta_key
----------------------
_featured  |   1
_featured  |   1
_featured  |   1
```

I want to change (all) the `meta_key` values to `0` only if the value of `meta_value` = `_featured`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have 3 rows where Meta_value = _featured. Can you change one of them to another value, and then describe which Meta_key value you want for each separate row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table_name set meta_key = 0 where meta_value = '_featured';
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Meta_key = 0 WHERE Meta_value = '_featured';
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use where condition

```
update your_table
set meta_key = 0
where meta_value = '_featured';
```

if u need to update multiple values

```
update your_table
    set meta_key = case meta_value
                    when '_featured'
                    then 0
                    else
                    1
                  END;
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, use single quotes for string literals.